# how can i do reverse sorting using linux commands

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, sed

i have file.txt like this

It is necessary to use a script or command to make it look like this:

i try `sort -k2,2nr file.txt`  it works, but I also change the column in the middle)
maybe you can help me with something, I also know that **AWK** can work with the column specified in $, but I can't understand how to do it correctly

Comment: `sort` does not modify the contents of a line; your expected output shows that you're modifying the content of the various lines; not sure how/why you'd think that sorting lines would also modify your lines ... ?

Comment: when I run this command I get the result but it also changes the middle column, just the sort output can be redirected to a file like  > results.txt

Comment: Your command syntax works perfectly on my system (`sort --version` result is `sort (GNU coreutils) 9.0`). Do you really call GNU sort command (`/usr/bin/sort`) ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggesting this simplified `awk` script:

##### `script.awk`

```
{ # read each line from input file, NR is internal variable `Number of Row`
  arr1[NR] = $1; # read column #1 into arr1
  arr2[NR] = $2; # read column #2 into arr2
  arr3[NR] = $3; # read column #3 into arr3
}
END { # post processing after reading input file.
  for (i = NR; i > 0; i--){ # reverse read the arrays from top to bottom
    print arr1[i], arr2[NR + 1 - i], arr3[i]; # orderly output arr1, arr3, but reverse order arr2
  }
}
```

##### `running:`

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sort, sed and cat):

```
sort -k2,2n file |
sed -E 's/^\S+ (\S+).*/s#\\S+#\1#2/' |
cat -n |
sed -Ef - <(sort -k2,2nr file)
```

Sort column 2 of file in ascending order.

Extract column 2 and turn those values into a sed substitution script.

Apply line numbers to the above script.

Apply the script to the same file sorted by column 2 in descending order.

---

Same effect using paste:

```
paste <(sort -k2,2nr file) <(sort -k2,2n file) | 
sed -E 's/^(\S+) \S+ (\S+)\t\S+ (\S+) .*/\1 \3 \2/'
```